# Segmentation fault (exit code 139) when using pthread_join

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I'm doing some first steps with threads on Linux systems, and i have this error which occures on the base of a program that gets some `n` argument and creates `n` number of threads.

Here is the important part of the code:

**The function the threads should run:**

```
void* function(void* arg){
    int id = (long)arg;

    printf("Thread #%ld created!\n",id);

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

**Important part of code in the `main` function**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc != 3){
        printf("Usage: %s <num> <exp>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    int num = atoi(argv[1]), exp = atoi(argv[2]);
    long i;
    pthread_t threads[num];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    printf("Creating %d threads \n",num);

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i],&attr,function,(void*)i);
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Thread #%d is %ld\n", i, threads[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[num], NULL);
    }

}
```

Notice the last `for` loop with the `pthread_join` function, when i comment it out the program ends fine (exit code 0), but the output is obviously wrong since not all of the threads runs `function` before the main process exits.

When i don't comment it out i get `segmentation fault (core dumped)` when trying to run using the terminal in my Linux OS and `Process finished with exit code 139` when running in my IDE (CLion).

I couldn't find anything i've done wrong as it's a very basic program that shouldn't have anything hard to find, what is the problem that causes the error?

Comment: Tip: "segmentation fault" and "Process finished with exit code 139" are synonymous. 139 = 0x80 | 11, which is what the shell returns as exit code when the program it executes is killed by signal 11, segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have used `pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);` instead of `pthread_join(threads[num], NULL);`. Suppose, the `num` is set to 4 via argument. Then `threads[num]` points to 5th element of array which does not exist as you have allocated an array of only 4 elements.

Comment: well kind of embarassing... Didn't notice that, stupid me... Thanks!